# How to add another app (option 1, 2, 3 etc) from current app (main app)?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to have multiple options of the app (separate FB app instances) and be able to add them from the main app? If yes where I can find some info how to do that?

I'm trying to install an app to the page multiple times, but what I know it is not possible so what I'm looking for is to create a main app with options as separate FB apps aka "Install Another Tab". I saw few apps which utilize that way.

Comment: No, you'd have to use multiple app IDs :- you could point multiple URLs to the same codebase, and have which URL is used dictate which app ID and app secret to use?

Comment: OK. Is there any function/shortcode to add a new tab form the app which I need to call as URL? Thanks

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs

Comment: One more question, but not related to the main topic. I have set fluid height but iframe always has attribute height 800px. Any idea why?

Comment: I went to the documentation but is not clear enough what I need to do like it was with an old way `http://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key={YOUR_APP_KEY}&pages=1&page={YOUR_PAGE_ID}`